# Show that $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)\leq\omega^{\alpha}$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am tackling this problem: "Show that $\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)\leq\omega^{\alpha}$". However I'm going on writing pages and pages trying to come up with a reasonable proof, without succeeding.

Here $\Gamma(\alpha,\beta):=$ the order type of the set $\{(\xi,\eta): (\xi,\eta)<(\alpha,\beta)\}$, and $(\alpha,\beta)<(\gamma,\delta)$ if and only if either $max\{\alpha,\beta\}<max\{\gamma,\delta\}$ or $max\{\alpha,\beta\}=max\{\gamma,\delta\} \wedge \alpha<\gamma$ or $max\{\alpha,\beta\}=max\{\gamma,\delta\} \wedge \alpha=\gamma \wedge \beta<\delta$.

I tried to use induction on $\alpha$, but the case of $\alpha$ successor is a mess, and I don't think there could be a simple way out. Therefore I tried to show the fact directly, using the order defined on couples of ordinals (it is really convenient to draw a cartesian plain with the first and the second element of the couples on the axis, realising that the order follows a sort of square-rule). Neither does it seem to work!
Anyone coming up with a good idea? I need some help, please, I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $\gamma_\alpha=\Gamma(\alpha\times\alpha)$. Then $\gamma_{\alpha+1}=\gamma_\alpha+\color{crimson}{\alpha}+\color{blue}{\alpha+1}=\gamma_\alpha+\alpha\cdot2+1$. (Here $\color{crimson}{\alpha}$ is for the top edge of the enlarged square, and $\color{blue}{\alpha+1}$ is for the righthand edge.) If $\gamma_\alpha\le\omega^\alpha$, then

$$\gamma_{\alpha+1}\le\omega^\alpha+\alpha\cdot2+1\;,$$

and you’d like to show that this is at most $\omega^{\alpha+1}$.

Suppose that you knew that $\alpha\cdot\omega\le\omega^\alpha$; then you’d have

$$\gamma_{\alpha+1}\le\omega^\alpha+\alpha\cdot2+1\le\omega^\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega\le\omega^\alpha\cdot2\le\omega^{\alpha+1}\;.$$

Try to prove that $\alpha\cdot\omega\le\omega^\alpha$ by induction on $\alpha$.

Comment: Do you know if this ordering of a product of ordered sets has a name?

Comment: @nombre: I've not seen any name for it.

Comment: @nombre: I know it as Gödel ordering or Gödel's pairing function (where you map a pair to its ordertype).

Comment: @martin.koeberl: Now that you mention it, I think that I have run across the name long ago. It's discussed in [this MO question and answers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112079/what-is-gödels-pairing-function-on-ordinals).

Comment: @martin.koeberl: Thanks to both of you for the information!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for the clear explanation!

Comment: @stemushu: You're very welcome.

Comment: This well-order is used in Kunen's Set Theory to obtain a bijection from the set $k\times k$ to $k$ when k is an infinite cardinal ordinal,(...because OT$(k\times k)\geq$ OT$(\{0\}\times k)=k,$  but pred $((x,x))<k $ for all $x\in k)$... but he does not give it a name.